# Is is possible to have symfony2 log missing translation strings so that I know what needs adding to my xilff files?

Tags: symfony, internationalization, xliff

I have a symfony project in which I've been through my twig templates and added `{% trans %}...{% endtrans %}` or adding translations like `{{ title|trans }}` where appropriate. I've also added a messages.de.xliff file and that is working perfectly for the few translations I have tried.

Is there a way I can get a list of strings missing from my xliff file? It's quite hard to keep track of every translation as I add it. It seems like it should log a failure to get a translation in a log file somewhere, but I've been googling a while and can't find anything.

Answer (score 2):

Hi Try following May Be helpful.

https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSTranslationBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.rst

Very powerful tool and definitely takes care of you problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very crappy patch to apply in `vendor/symfony` that does what I need. Probably not to be run on a production server!

```
diff --git a/src/Symfony/Component/Translation/MessageCatalogue.php b/src/Symfony/Component/Translation/MessageCatalogue.php
index b55676f..98a5cba 100644
--- a/src/Symfony/Component/Translation/MessageCatalogue.php
+++ b/src/Symfony/Component/Translation/MessageCatalogue.php
@@ -128,6 +128,8 @@ class MessageCatalogue implements MessageCatalogueInterface
             return $this->fallbackCatalogue->get($id, $domain);
         }

+        error_log('Translation not found: "' . $id . '"');
+
         return $id;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to overwrite the `Translator` and `MessageCatalogue` classes.

**Translator:**

```
class RegisteringTranslator extends \Symfony\Component\Translation\Translator
{
    protected function loadCatalogue($locale)
    {
        parent::loadCatalogue($locale);

        if ( ! $this->catalogues[$locale] instanceof RegisteringMessageCatalogue) {
            $registeringCatalogue = new RegisteringMessageCatalogue($locale);
            $registeringCatalogue->addCatalogue($this->catalogues[$locale]);
            $this->catalogues[$locale] = $registeringCatalogue;
        }
    }
}
```

**Catalogue:**

```
class RegisteringMessageCatalogue extends \Symfony\Component\Translation\MessageCatalogue
{
    public function get($id, $domain = 'messages')
    {
        if ( ! $this->has($id, $domain)) {
            error_log('Translation not found: "' . $id . '"');
        }

        return parent::get($id, $domain);
    }

}
```

Of course you need to use the new Translator class.

Also not very nice because it uses the protected methods and properties of `Translator` class. But better than changing the Symfony code directly.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I'm posting here just in case somebody still has the same problem.

Starting from Symfony 2.6, you'll find a very nice addition to the web debug toolbar that shows how many translations you're missing.

[image]

By clicking it, the profiler will display a detailed list of missing translation.

Works out of the box, without any configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you should be able to use the Symfony command `debug:translation` via `app/console`.

Something like this:

```
$ php app/console debug:translation --only-missing <locale> <Bundle Name>
```

A concrete example would be:

```
$ php app/console debug:translation --only-missing nl AppBundle
```

That would output:

```
 ----------- ---------- ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ------------------------------------------
  State       Domain     Id                                                                                                      Message Preview (nl)
 ----------- ---------- ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ------------------------------------------
   missing    messages   Create a clean selection                                                                                Create a clean selection
   missing    messages   New Selection                                                                                           New Selection
   missing    messages   login.labels.geoserver_url                                                                              login.labels.geoserver_url
```